# Get connection handle details of Oracle resource handle in PHP for debugging validity of connection

Tags: php, oracle

**Scenario**

I use a function, namely `oci_connect`, to connect to an Oracle database.  Outputting `oci_num_rows($handle)` displays 0, which does not correspond to another page output that displays a value above 0 which I observe on the same query but possibly different connection information.

**Problem**

I want to output the details of this resource for inspecting why my query (which has been checked for spelling and parameter matching successfully and query parameters present) is returning 0 rows.

I tried `echo($conn)` but it returns

```
resource(8, oci8 connection)
```

to the browser.

**Question**

How do I output the connection specific details of the resource handle using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have been able to `var_dump(get_defined_vars())` and it displays all values of all variable values.

I have been unable to find the line there the variables are set at runtime, at least the most recent line, at runtime.